# Magento 1.9.2.2 cannot create account and login on frontend

Tags: magento, firefox, frontend, magento-1.9

**I'm using Firefox** and I started to have a problem. I can't create new user in a Magento 1.9.2.2 in the frontend and also I can't login with a register user. In the backend I can create the user without problems.

**This was not happening some time ago.**

I tried these solutions and didn't work:

- Add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` to some files of my template.
- Delete `var/cache` and `var/session`.
- Change life cycle of the cookies.
- Change domain name of the cookies.

Any idea? :(

Comment: Check this https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Customer-Registration-not-working-in-1-9-2-2/td-p/20563 and http://www.dudesquare.nl/blog/2015/11/02/customer-registration-not-working-magento-1-9-2-2/ it might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot create a customer or login after applying patch SUPEE-6788 or upgrading to Magento 1.9.2.2 or later, this might be caused by missing form keys.

Make sure to add form keys to all of your (custom) template files:

In `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/customer/form/register.phtml` and `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Add

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

after

```
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
```